# Why does cygwin use Visaul Studio BuildTools instead of gcc?

Tags: cygwin

First of all I am very new to cygwin and I didn't find similar question
It was pointed out that to install Python lib `hdt` that contains c++ code it is necessary to use Cygwin because some headers exist only in Posix.
Trying to install the lib earlier I installed MS BuildTools. When I tried to install the lib without Cygwin on Windows it was an error

```
    BitSequence.cpp
    hdt-cpp-1.3.3/libcds/include/libcdsBasics.h(27): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґв
бп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Buil
dTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exi
t status 2
```

The error is from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
And I've find out that there is no way to avoid the error on Windows, and in won't be the error on Linux or using Cygwin.
Now I try to install Python lib in Cygwin. I do the same in Cygwin terminal (`pip install hdt`) and get the same error from Visual Studio.
Why doesn't Cygwin use gcc? I think that's a point of Cygwin usage. Of course if it uses VS it gets the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are NOT using the cygwin Python and using instead a windows Version:

```
$ which pip
which: no pip in (/home/Marco/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/lapack:/usr/sbin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/d/utility)

$ which pip2
/usr/bin/pip2

$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Verify you have installed a Cygwin Python,

```
$ cygcheck -cd |grep "python3. "
python3                                 3.8.3-1
python36                                3.6.10-1
python37                                3.7.7-1
python38                                3.8.3-1

$ cygcheck -cd |grep "python2. "
python2                                 2.7.18-1
python27                                2.7.18-1
```

and try again with EG

```
Usage:
  /usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip <command> [options]


  /usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install hdt
```